# how to get a pass value get from userPref to another js file gadget

Tags: wso2, google-gadget

I am currently working on creating custom gadget for our portal.I have added a user preference chart-type(drop down list) to populate chart by getting chart type from user and setting up that value for gadget configurations and create gadget.So I can get the user input of gadget chart-type by below js code in the index.xml file.

```html
<script>
  gadgets.util.registerOnLoadHandler(
    function() {
      var prefs = new gadgets.Prefs();
      var content = prefs.getString('ChartType');
      console.log("********" + content);

    });
</script>
```

I can see console log with respect of user input.I need to pass this value for another js files under the folder js/gadgetconfig.js
Can anyone please guide me through this?

Comment: You mean you need to pass this value to a function in js/gadgetconfig.js ?

Comment: ya of course I have js file called gadgetconfig.js

Comment: What's the issue that you're facing in calling this function ?

Comment: Is there any restriction that we need to give userPref name and display-name as same.I can get this value after I change to same as display-name